# Firefox Context Menu Item Overlay: Why is every Menu Item Showing?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I created an context menu item overlay  with

```
<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu" onpopupshowing="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.test(event)">
      <menuitem id="thumbnail-show-etes" 
        label="My Label"
        class="menuitem-iconic"
        image="chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/favicon.png"
        oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.injectScript('tap_browser.js');"/>
    </menupopup>
```

And the function test(event) is

```
test: function(aEvent) {
        var localName = aEvent.target.triggerNode.localName;
        this.clickOnImage = (localName == "img") ? true : false;
        console.log(localName, ' click on image ', this.clickOnImage);
    }
```

I don't understand why calling this function will show every menu item?
[image]

**Solution**

I figure out the solution was to change from "onpopupshowing" to "onpopupshown"

```
 <menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu" onpopupshown="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.test(event)">
          <menuitem id="thumbnail-show-etes" 
            label="My Label"
            class="menuitem-iconic"
            image="chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/favicon.png"
            oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.injectScript('tap_browser.js');"/>
        </menupopup>
```

Comment: Try to change id of menupopup `contentAreaContextMenu` to something custom.

Comment: I changed the menupopup id to something custom. Now my custom menu item doesn't show up when I right clicked. I want the menu item to be part of the default context menu when the user right clicks.

Comment: You have to attach the menupopup to your node. There's an xul property called menu for which you set the id, im pretty sure.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Property/menu

Comment: So <menupopup id="customID" menu="contentAreaContextMenu" ...? I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: no the menu attribute goes on the element you want opening this menu. so like a toolbarbutton.

Comment: I want a <menuitem> on the default context menu, not a UI element opening the menu. And I was able to do this with my code, its just when i added  onpopupshowing attribute it shows every element.

Comment: I solved it, it was changing the attribute from "onshowingpopup" to "onshownpopup"

Comment: Can you post your solution as a solution below. Comparing this bugged code to your new code will teach us all something.

Comment: Done. I posted the solution.

Comment: Post solution by answering your own topic. You are allowd to do this. It is recommended actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It's to change from "onpopupshowing" to "onpopupshown"

```
 <menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu" onpopupshown="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.test(event)">
          <menuitem id="thumbnail-show-etes" 
            label="My Label"
            class="menuitem-iconic"
            image="chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/favicon.png"
            oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.injectScript('tap_browser.js');"/>
        </menupopup>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function to this:

```
test: function(aEvent) {
var img;
        if(gContextMenu.onImage) {
            img = aEvent.originalTarget
        }
        else if(gContextMenu.hasBGImage && !gContextMenu.isTextSelected) {
            var imgURL = gContextMenu.bgImageURL;
        }

        console.log(img,' click on image ', img);
    }
```

I am just experimenting